# React app website works locally but won't work once uploaded to Vercel with GitHub

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vercel

I keep finding this as I am creating a website using Vercel and GitHub. I can get the website working just fine on local but it's not working here. Apparently the text and react logo should be in my App.jsx file but I deleted it and made this.

This is my app.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './components/header/Header.jsx'
import Nav from './components/nav/Nav.jsx'
import About from './components/about/About.jsx'
import Experience from './components/experience/Experience.jsx'
import Services from './components/services/Services.jsx'
import Portfolio from './components/portfolio/Portfolio.jsx'
import Contact from './components/contact/Contact.jsx'
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer.jsx'

const App = () => {
  return (
      <>
        <Header />
        <Nav />
        <About />
        <Experience />
        <Services />
        <Portfolio />
        <Contact />
        <Footer />
      </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Are there any error messages in the logs?

Comment: No, only warnings npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
14:45:02.850

Comment: What about in the vercel build logs?

Comment: and a warning for this:  <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>

Comment: This is the vercel build warning: npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
14:44:52.661 npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

Comment: Thank you so much for encouraging me to look at errors! had to add to the json; "build": "CI=false react-scripts build",

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding to the json, although I know should just fix the errors...
"build": "CI=false react-scripts build",